# systemctl start does not detach

Tags: mysql, systemd, mariadb

I got a machine where the settings got changed too much...

We try to reanable mariadb-server. Now we got this far, that after `systemctl start mariadb.service` the service runns. But the terminal is still blocked. The `systemctl` command does not finish till we write `systemctl stop mariadb.service`.

Our workaround now is to start via a `screen -dms systemctl start mariadb.service` but I want to fix it.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: `systemctl status mariadb.service` runs its output through a pager, in case the output is large. Type `SPACE` to page through the output, "`q`" to quit.

Comment: I mad a very bad mistake. I mixed up status and start. Thank you for looking at it, but sadly the problem is that the start process does not detach.